# TSQL Select into Temporary Table and add Id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I'm currently working on an T-SQL Query on SQL Server 2014.

I'm trying to Select data from 1 table into another and add an extra Id to each row.

My query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @TargetId = 1

SELECT * INTO #tmpProjects FROM @Projects 
UNION SELECT @TargetId AS 'TargetId'
```

Unfortunately this Select statement does not work...

My desired output *#tmpProjects* should look like this:

```
ProjectId |    Title    | Manager   | TargetId 
----------+-------------+-----------+-----------
1         |   projectX  |   1123    |  1 
2         |   projectY  |   2245    |  1
3         |   projectZ  |   3335    |  1
```

In my importing table *@Projects*, I get the columns ProjectId, Title and Manager.

Do you know how to solve this issue? Thus to select into a temporary table and add an extra Id?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just add it to the select: `select ProjectId, Title, Manager, @TargetId AS TargetId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   create table #tmpProjects 
     (
        ProjectId varchar(20) , 
        Title varchar(20) ,
         Manager varchar(20), 
         TargetId varchar(20)
     )
DECLARE @Projects table (ProjectId varchar(20) , Title varchar(20) ,Manager varchar(20))
insert into @Projects values ('p1' , 't1' , 'm1')
insert into @Projects values ('p2' , 't2' , 'm2')
select * from @Projects

------------- **solution starts here**  ---------------
DECLARE @TargetId int 
set @TargetId = 1
insert into #tmpProjects ( ProjectId ,Title , Manager ,  TargetId )
select  ProjectId ,Title , Manager , @TargetId
from @Projects

select * from #tmpProjects
```

Comment: I solved it that way in the end. Thanks for the detailed example! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an extra column to your table then you need to Alter it to add a new column.
For keeping default value in the column you can use the **DEFAULT** keyword and provide the value. 
Please find the query below, I hope this will be helpful:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS(ProjectId int, Title varchar(50), Manager varchar(50))
INSERT INTO PROJECTS 
VALUES
(1, 'projectX' , '1123'),
(2, 'projectY' , '2245'),
(3, 'projectZ' , '3335')
GO
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #tmpProjects FROM PROJECTS
ALTER TABLE  #tmpProjects ADD TargetId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (1)
SELECT * FROM #tmpProjects
END
```

You cannot use any variable inside default keyword. But you can create a scalar function to use any variable of your choice.
You can check this link how to use the scalar function to add the default value to your column.

[ALTER TABLE with programmatically determined constant DEFAULT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659669/alter-table-with-programmatically-determined-constant-default-value)

One more thing here.You must explicitly define your column as **NOT NULL** if you want to use **DEFAULT** keyword to insert default values. 
If you are not doing it then it will hold only **NULL** values and will not insert any value which you have provided with **DEFAULT** keyword

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE  #tmpProjects ADD TargetId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (1)
```

This will insert **1** in your TargetId column. But,

```
ALTER TABLE  #tmpProjects ADD TargetId INT DEFAULT (1)
```

This will insert **NULL** in your TargetId column

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks for this detailed explanation!! It is indeed helpful :))